# Update field datatype after publishing DAC Extension

Tags: acumatica

I have created a customization which contains DAC extension. There are few extra fields added to Stock Item screen (InventoryItem table). After publishing, the customer had a requirements for one of the field to change its datatype from string to bool. I did updated in customization and published it. However, it did not updated in database. As a result it was throwing an error. Is there anything I am missing here? Please suggest.

Comment: if you open the XML of your customization, what is the column type in your Sql tag for the field you are referring to? Does your column name start with "Usr"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acumatica doesn't delete columns out of the database as a result of a change in your customization.  You have two options here, you can drop the column via SQL command and publish, or more realistically, you can just create a new UDF with a different name and change your code.

Comment: This is partially incorrect. If you are talking about "Usr" fields they will always remain. But if you doing a true table extension where you split into your own table it will delete the column if removed from your customization table statement. It will not delete the table as a whole if you remove the table from the customization project.

Comment: Brendan, yes that is true. Here I am talking about Usr fields which it is not deleting. Ideally I would expect Acumatica to update if I change any fields as it is possible through SQL anyway. But it is not doing. Patrick, I have done the same way already but wanted to know the better way. What if customer has bunch of fields wanted to change.  In that way we will end up with those many unnecessary fields in base table.

Comment: I usually review the XML of my customization project. See if you can find any unchanged references to the old data type and change it to your new datatype. To view the XML just click on your customization project to open the customization window and then under file click view XML

Comment: Hey Krunal, the rule of thumb for ERP is that you never want to be the guy who deleted valuable data out of the accounting system.  Acumatica is going to avoid an instance where they are blamed for data loss.  This is also why they emphasize that custom dev should be completed on the developer's site before publishing to live.  If this is something that needs to be done, you're best best is to pull down a snapshot (or SQL backup) from the cloud, install in dev environment, fix, and then publish it back to the cloud, probably as a new instance of Acumatica.  This will require Acu help.